# How to Transform value from selection data into Input Textbox

Tags: html, jsp

```
<select name="OCCUPATION_CLASS" onChange="fnOccpClass();"  disabled>
        <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
                  <%
                    for (int i = 0; i < vCLASS_CODE.size(); i++) 
                    {

                        String sCODE    = (String) vCLASS_CODE.elementAt(i);
                        String sDESCP   = (String) vCLASS_DESCP.elementAt(i);   

                  %>
                      <option value="<%=sCODE%>" <% if (OCCUPATION_CLASS.equals(sCODE)){out.println("selected");} %>><%=sDESCP%></option><% } %>  
</select>
```

i try to display the value = "sDESCP" into textbox .. but failed

```
<input type="text" value="<%=sDESCP%>" name="OCCUPATION_CLASS">
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: The scope of the variables sCODE and sDESCP are available with in for loop only(Local variables). External access to this variables results error.

Comment: ya @SurendarKannan are right.. 

How can i make the variables available for external access?

Comment: Initiate string variables globally in jsp and access it everywhere. Ex: At the top of your jsp, <% String sCode = "";String sDESCP="";%>

Answer (score 0):

Modify input textbox as

```
<input id="inp" "type="text" value="<%=sDESCP%>" name="OCCUPATION_CLASS">
```

and the drop down as

```
<select name="OCCUPATION_CLASS" id="dd" onChange="fnOccpClass();"  disabled>
        <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
                  <%
                    for (int i = 0; i < vCLASS_CODE.size(); i++) 
                    {

                        String sCODE    = (String) vCLASS_CODE.elementAt(i);
                        String sDESCP   = (String) vCLASS_DESCP.elementAt(i);   

                  %>
                      <option value="<%=sCODE%>" <% if (OCCUPATION_CLASS.equals(sCODE)){out.println("selected");} %>><%=sDESCP%></option><% } %>  
</select>
```

Now in fn0ccpClass() function in javascript code section

```
function fnOccpClass() {
     document.getElementById("inp").value=document.getElementById

('dd').options[document.getElementById('dd').selectedIndex].text;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, um ..right now my case was i want to remove whole selection box, and make the sDESCP show in textbox

Comment: hey its the solution for the problem where you were failed.. the value of sDESCP will be displayed in the textbox... rest of you can remove or disabe the selection box by modifying function             fnOccpClass() {
     document.getElementById("inp").value=document.getElementById

('dd').options[document.getElementById('dd').selectedIndex].text;   document.getElementById("jumpMenu").disabled = true;
    }